# What is the difference between timescale and fps?

Tags: ios, swift, object, video

```
let assetItem = AVAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "videofile"));
let timescale = assetItem.duration.timescale;
let fps = assetItem.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].nominalFrameRate;`
```

What is the difference between `timescale` and `fps` ?
I print the value of timescale from different videos , but it always is 600.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The movie’s **timescale** is the timing resolution of the movie per second. Dividing the duration of a movie by its timescale will tell you the approximate length of the movie, in seconds.
*(ex: 1200 time units divided by a timescale of 600 units/second gives us 2 seconds).*

The **fps, or frames per second**, of a movie tells us how many individual video images exist in the movie every second. The higher the fps of a movie, the smoother the apparent motion of the movie will be (assuming, that is, that the individual frames are all in some way unique). Some common fps rates are 15, 24, 29.97, and 30. Our movie file in this example runs at 15 frames per second, which works out to a new frame of video every 40 time units, or about every 66.7 milliseconds.

Comment: "timescale is the timing resolution of the movie per second" can you elaborate more on this?  Still having trouble understanding.